# Oracle Service Bus 12c - How to pass Array Data type in Java Callout

Tags: oracle12c, weblogic12c, osb

I've created a java class that has an argument of String[] Data type but couldn't figure out how to pass an array. What i've tried is putting the array inside single quotes but when I run the Proxy Service, it returns null.

Request Arguments:

```
java.lang.String = 'EDGF.FMW_SELECT_TABLE_NAME'
java.lang.String[] = '{"jdbc:oracle:thin:@IP:PORT:SID", "User", "Password"}'
java.lang.String[] = '{$body/oraf:Order/oraf:var1,$body/oraf:Order/oraf:var2}'
```

[image]

The way I set the output is like this in response

```
<oraf:queryResult>{data($resultSetTable)}</oraf:queryResult>
```

[image]

I've tried running the Java Class with the same arguments and it returns a result.

Result from Running Java Class:

```
, 49451234, , , 2019-02-13 00:00:00.0, , 12341234, , null,
```

Response from Running Proxy Service

```
<soapenv:Body>
<oraf:queryResult xmlns:oraf="http://xmlns.oracle.com/db/SPName"/>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Answer (score 0):

To put array into JavaCallout you can use fn:tokenize function for example:

create $variable ealier for example by using assign ("var1,var2,var3") then into your argument paste below line: 
fn:tokenize($variable,',')

Answer (score 0):

I agree to use fn:tokenize(). However, in the OSB environment (12c IntegratedWeblogicServer) on my WindowsOS, I could not use an OSB variable to pass the resulting array (in fact: Xquery sequence) to the JavaCallout. It started working for me when I placed the fn:tokenize() in the input arguments-expression of the JavaCallout itself.